# How to use JSDoc3 to document nested namespaces

Tags: javascript, namespaces, documentation, jsdoc

I'm having trouble using JSDoc3 to document code that's structured along these lines

```
/**
 * @namespace MyNamespace.MySubNamespace
 */

(function (MyNamespace) {
    MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.Foo = {
        doSomething: function (someParam) {
            // doing it
        }
    }
})(window.MyNamespace)
```

How would I use JSDoc3 to document that `MyNamespace` contains `MySubNamespace` which contains `Foo`?  Further how would I associate `doSomething` with `Foo` and document its parameter `someParam`?

A limitation I have is that I can't add documentation to the file in which `MyNamespace` and `MySubNamespace` are declared.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Figured it out.  Hope this solution helps others.

```
/**
 * @namespace MyNamespace.MySubNamespace
 */

 (function (MyNamespace) {
     /**
      * Foo namespace
      * @namespace Foo
      * @memberOf MyNamespace.MySubNamespace
      */ 
     var Foo = {
         /**
          * Does something.
          * @memberOf MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.Foo
          * @param {object} someParam Some parameter.
          */
         doSomething: function (someParam) {
             // doing it
         }
     };
     MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.Foo = Foo;
 })(window.MyNamespace)
```

Comment: This still helps (in 2022) when trying to add modules to a namespace