# Documenting a Marionette Module with RequireJS and JSDoc3

Tags: javascript, requirejs, marionette, jsdoc

I'm finally taking some time to formally document my Marionette code, but I'm running into some issues with JSDoc3 and Marionette modules.

How would I go about documenting a Marionette module defined like this:

```
//Module1.js
define([... , 'views'], function(..., 'views'){
    "usestrict";

    //Marionette Module definition:
    return function(...marionette module params...){
        ...
    }
}
```

and then hook it up in the docs to a view defined like this:

```
//views.js
define([...], function(...){
    "usestrict";

    var itemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        ...
    };

    //Uses itemView in a region
    return Marionette.Layout.extend({
        ...
        //do stuff with itemView
        ...
    });
}
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: You say "I'm running into some issues with JSDoc3 and Marionette modules." What are these issues you ran into? There are also [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230971/how-do-i-jsdoc-a-nested-objects-methods) that cover the general methods by which to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I don't know how I missed it in my own searching.

Comment: To answer your question, I was getting a blank index.html template. Thanks to your link, I figured it out! Posting answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Louis I figured out how to get the module to be recognized. I was then able to mess around with it enough to get the view registered as a class to the module.

Module1.js:

```
/** @module Module1 */
define([... , 'views'], function(..., 'views'){
    "usestrict";

    /** @lends module:Module1 */

    //Marionette Module definition:
    return function(...marionette module params...){
        ...
    }
}
```

and View.js:

```
define([...], function(...){
    "usestrict";

    /**
    * @name module:Module1.Module1/Views/itemView
    * @constructor
    */
    var itemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend(
    /** @lends module:Module1.Module1/Views/itemView.prototype */
    {
        ...
    };

    /**
    * @name module:Module1.Module1/Views/layoutView
    * @constructor
    */
    return Marionette.Layout.extend(
    /** @lends module:Module1.Module1/Views/layoutView.prototype */
    {
        ...
        //do stuff with itemView
        ...
    });
}
```

A couple of notes:

- In the @name for the views, the .Module1/ isn't really necessary, but it makes it easier to find in the doc webpage
- The itemView is technically private in this example since it doesn't get returned but I want to be able to find it in the docs