# How to document a JavaScript object with properties and methods with parameters using JSDoc comments

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

```
const objectname = {
    property: 0,
    set (value) {
        this.property = value;
    }
}
```

How would you document these example lines with JSDoc comments?

This is what I already tried but it doesn't show `objectName.set` as a method and doesn't show its parameters.

```
/**
 * Represents an object with a property and a set method.
 * @typedef {object} ObjectName
 * @property {number} property - The numeric property of the object.
 * @property {Function} set - Sets the property value to the specified value.
 * @param {number} value - The value to set the property to.
 * @returns {void}
 */

/**
 * An instance of ObjectName.
 * @type {ObjectName}
 */
const objectName = {
    property: 0,

    /**
     * Sets the property value to the specified value.
     * @param {number} value - The value to set the property to.
     * @returns {void}
     */
    set(value) {
        this.property = value;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @param and @returns tags belongs inside the JSDoc comment for the set method, not in the @typedef comment for ObjectName.

VSCode works if I remove

```
    /**
     * An instance of ObjectName.
     * @type {ObjectName}
     */
```

Here is a corrected version

```js
/**
 * Represents an object with a property and a set method.
 * @typedef {object} ObjectName
 * @property {number} property - The numeric property of the object.
 * @property {Function} set - Sets the property value to the specified value.
 */

const objectName = {
  property: 0,

  /**
   * Sets the property value to the specified value.
   * @param {number} value - The value to set the property to.
   * @returns {void}
   */
  set(value) {
    this.property = value;
  }
};
```

**VSCode:**

[image]

Comment: `ObjectName` refers to type and `objectName` is a variable name. I don't see any problem here. In the @param and @returns part you are correct

Comment: works kind of like i wanted but when using the set method it doesn't display the correct parameters

im using vscode btw

just a screenshot of the issue
https://imgur.com/a/IWNc17x

Comment: @mplungjan The popup which shows parameters when using functions is displayed correctly but it doesn't work for methods inside objects. I also tried it on a different object and it's the same problem. Maybe VSCode interprets jsDoc diffrently?

Comment: Yeah it works for classes.
Do you think that it would be better to make my JavaScript objects as classes instead of simple object declarations even when the object would be constructed once.
Sorry for asking so many questions haha.

Comment: That completely depends on your needs. I see a lot of questions about jsdoc and methods. Have a look here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230971/how-do-i-jsdoc-a-nested-objects-methods

Comment: @rickydickydodahgrimes I think I solved it. I get the correct popup if I remove the extra blurb you had just before the const

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a JSDoc expert, and maybe I'm being too simplistic, but this seems to work:

```
/**
 * An object that blah blah blah...
 */
const objectname = {
    /**
     * The numeric property of the object.
     * @type number
     */
    property: 0,
    /**
     * Sets the `property` to the given value.
     * @param {number} value - The value to set the property to.
     * @returns {void}
     */
    set(value) {
        this.property = value;
    },
};
```

When I use that in VS Code, I get the type and description of things (including the parameter type on `set`) in popups and such.

Comment: This is the correct way. It's ugly and verbose and I hate it but it is what it is. It also works for annotating TS interfaces and object types.

Comment: yeah it doesnt look pleasing but it works and you get a correct pop up and that's what i wanted

Comment: @JaredSmith what do you mean by saying it's verbose sorry i just don't understand

Comment: @rickydickydodahgrimes verbose == wordy and you end up having more lines of comments than actual code. But yeah, it'll do what you want here.

Comment: @JaredSmith ah i understand i've been trying to avoid that but there doesn't seem to be any other way of documenting objects that would work as intended

Comment: So the JSCode issue was due to `/**  * An instance of ObjectName.  * @type {ObjectName}  */` before the const