# How to use JSDoc to document my structure?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Below is my code structure:

```
const kind = [];

kind.sample= factory( function() {

const sample = {};
sample.init = function() {...}

const privateFunction = function() {...}

return sample;

} );

function factory( protoFn )
{
return () => Object.create( protoFn() );
}

kind.sample();
```

And this is how I have tried to document it so far:

```
/**
 * @namespace kind
 * @description keeps references of objects' factory functions.
*/
const kind = [];

/**
 * @description define prototype function
 * @method
*/
kind.sample= factory( function() {

/**
 * @namespace kind.sample <- does not work
 * @description prototype
*/    
const sample = {};

 /**
 * @memberof kind.sample
 */
sample.init = function() {...}

/**
 * @private
 */
const privateFunction = function() {...}

return sample;

} );

function factory( protoFn )
{
return () => Object.create( protoFn() );
}

kind.sample();
```

As you can see above, I want to create a `sample` namespace under `kind` namespace. JSDoc generates it under `kind` namespace but when I click on it, nothing happens and I cannot see the methods( like `init` ). However if I create it as a separate namespace e.g `sample`, it works fine. Could you tell me how can I put `sample` namespace as a nested namespace under `kind`?

Comment: Does this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17119248/11147608) make some sense to you?

Comment: That doesn't work for me